# Query using Group By, Top N and Sum

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have looked through the forum and can find a variety of examples to solve my problem but just cannot put everything together.

My situation is typical that I would like to show the Top 10 customers (Orders.[Customer Name]) by group (Shop_Lookup.ShopGroup])  for their total revenue.

I can get so far in producing the overall Top 10 regardless of ShopGroup but just cannot get my head around getting the Sub Query to work.  My current code is -

```
SELECT TOP 10 Orders.[Customer Name], 
              Sum(Orders.[Actual Revenue]) AS [SumOfActual Revenue],
              Orders.[This Month], 
              Shop_Lookup.[ShopGroup]

FROM Orders 
INNER JOIN Shop_Lookup ON Orders.[ShopID] = ShopLookup.[ShopID]    
WHERE ((Orders.[This Month])="current")    
GROUP BY Orders.[Customer Name], Orders.[This Month], Shop_Lookup.[ShopGroup]    
ORDER BY Sum(Orders.[Actual Revenue]) DESC;
```

Comment: Good question.  If you don't get the right answer quickly consider adding a representation of the final result.

Answer (score 1):

**Completely AIR CODED !** Proceed with caution.

You can use Sub Query to get this !

```
SELECT 
    Orders.[Customer Name], 
    Sum(Orders.[Actual Revenue]) AS [SumOfActual Revenue],
    Orders.[This Month], 
    Shop_Lookup.[ShopGroup]
FROM 
    Orders
    INNER JOIN 
    Shop_Lookup 
    ON 
    Orders.[ShopID] = ShopLookup.[ShopID]    
WHERE 
    (
        (Orders.[This Month] = 'Current')
        AND
        (Orders.ShopID IN
            (SELECT 
                TOP 10 ShopID                            
            FROM 
                Orders AS Dupe                              
            WHERE 
                Dupe.ShopID = Orders.ShopID      
            )
        )
    )
GROUP BY 
    Orders.[Customer Name], 
    Orders.[This Month], 
    Shop_Lookup.[ShopGroup]    
ORDER BY 
    Sum(Orders.[Actual Revenue]) DESC;
```

More information on Subqueries : http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html

Comment: I didn't test this, but it looks good -- I'm going out on a limb and upvoting.

Comment: Thank you @Smandoli, in theory it should work. However without testing it cannot be confirmed. :) Thanks for the upvote !